# Custom event of Polymer custom element is handled more than one time

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer v1.0 with webcomponents-lite.js v0.7.11. I have created  custom element that scrolls images vertically or horizontally relative to scroll-direction attribute. My problem is that when i try to add several  to index page, the last  element loads images and works.Previous  elements do not work. Also i am listening custom event in Polymer ready function of custom element but only custom event of the most recently added custom element is handled more than one time (how many custom elements created).

```
(function () {
var element;
var imgData;
Polymer {
    is: 'image-scroller',
    properties{
        id: '',
        scrollDirection: '',
        imgJsonSrc: ''
    },

    ready: function () {
        element = this.querySelector("#imgContainer");

        $(element).on("ImageChanged",function (e){
            self.setScroller();
        });

        self.loadImagePathFromJSON(this.imgJSONSrc);

    },

    setScroller: function (){
        //Creates a custom scrollbar 
        var scrollViewHeight = this.querySelector("#scrollView").clientHeight;
        totalImageCount = imgData.images.length;
        scrollerHeight = parseFloat((scrollViewHeight / totalImageCount).toFixed(2));
        this.querySelector("#scroller").style.height = scrollerHeight+"px";
    },

    loadImagePathFromJSON: function(jsonSrc) {
        //Reads image paths from json file and creates an imgData object

        return imgData;
    },

    showImages: function(data){
        //Show images in div
    },
});
})();
```

Comment: Could you add code of the element you are developing?

Comment: @Scarygami i have added code summary in question, i hope it could be enough

Answer (score 2):

The `element` and `imgData` variable you define outside of the Polymer() scope will be shared for all instances of your element. So whenever you call `element = this.querySelector("#imgContainer");` this variable will be overwritten and only the most recent reference will be used, which is why only your last element works.

You have to use `this.element` and `this.imgData` inside of your element to keep them bound to an element instance.